# How can I reduce 2 nested match statements when each arm returns a different combination of a type with a type argument

Tags: generics, rust, nested, match

My problem: I have a function that returns a `Box<dyn Trait_1>`-object. Let's say I have `N=2` possible types at level 1 that implement this `Trait_1` and I want both of these types accessible via a match statement. But now these 2 possible types are each generic as well (but have to implement `Trait_2`) and I have `M=2` possible types at level 2 that I want to use. Now I can either have one match with 4 arms or 2 nested matches with 2 arms each. I have to write 4 statements that initialize this `Box`. This is very simple. But if I had `N=15` types at level 1 (that impl Trait_1) and 20 types at level 2 that impl some other `Trait_2` I'll end up writing 300 different initializations! That's a lot of work and also I will probably put in some errors.

I've written up a simple example of my problem with 2 nested match statements with each having 2 arms resulting in a total of 4 initializations (I've omitted the Trait-implementations)

```rust
pub trait Trait_1 {}
pub trait Trait_2 {}

pub struct SingleContainer<T: Trait_2> {
    item: T,
}

pub struct DoubleContainer<T: Trait_2> {
    item_1: T,
    item_2: T,
}

// -> impl Trait_1 for SingleContainer and DoubleContainer

struct X {
    number: f64,
}

struct Y {
    number: u32,
}

// -> impl Trait_2 for X and Y

fn main() {
    let a = // determined at runtime
    let b = // determined at runtime

    let thing = give_thing(a, b);
}

fn give_thing(thing_number: usize, thing_name: &str) -> Box<dyn Trait_1> {
    match thing_number {
        1 => match thing_name {
            "X" => Box::new(SingleContainer::<X>::default()),
            "Y" => Box::new(SingleContainer::<Y>::default()),
            _ => todo!(),
        },
        2 => match thing_name {
            "X" => Box::new(DoubleContainer::<X>::default()),
            "Y" => Box::new(DoubleContainer::<Y>::default()),
            _ => todo!(),
        },
        _ => todo!(),
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have difficulties seeing another way, as each of these things is a different type. I want that at compile time each of the possible combinations of (SingleContainer, DoubleContainer) and (X,Y) "exists" and therefor will be optimized. If there's a better way to achieve this please let me know! I basically only need a function that returns a `Box<dyn MyTrait>`-object that gets 2 arguments. But as each combination of arguments returns a different type I'm very confused!

Edit: Would blanket implementations help in this case in any way?

(If someone has a better way of phrasing my question, feel free to correct me!)

Comment: Depending on your use case, there are two solutions: `Box<dyn Trait>` like you did, or an `enum` (e.g. [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.9.0/either/enum.Either.html) if you only have two cases, or a custom `enum` if you have more).

Answer (score 1):

A little type metaprogramming can help here.

```rust
trait MakeTrait1 {
    type Make<T: Trait_2 + Default + 'static>: Trait_1 + Default + 'static;
}

struct MakeSingleContainer;
impl MakeTrait1 for MakeSingleContainer {
    type Make<T: Trait_2 + Default + 'static> = SingleContainer<T>;
}

struct MakeDoubleContainer;
impl MakeTrait1 for MakeDoubleContainer {
    type Make<T: Trait_2 + Default + 'static> = DoubleContainer<T>;
}

fn make_trait1<T: MakeTrait1>(thing_name: &str) -> Box<dyn Trait_1> {
    match thing_name {
        "X" => Box::new(T::Make::<X>::default()),
        "Y" => Box::new(T::Make::<Y>::default()),
        _ => todo!(),
    }
}

fn give_thing(thing_number: usize, thing_name: &str) -> Box<dyn Trait_1> {
    match thing_number {
        1 => make_trait1::<MakeSingleContainer>(thing_name),
        2 => make_trait1::<MakeDoubleContainer>(thing_name),
        _ => todo!(),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7baf6470ed06704657c0cd3d792e5076).

We basically create a type factory that for the inner type creates the outer type. Then we have a function that makes a runtime decision based on this type-level factory, and all left to do is to have a function that calls this function with each factory.

Comment: Thank you! I think it took quite a while for me to understand your code. But now I think I got it :-)
So at runtime the N * M different type-combinations (with N being the outer and M being the inner type) can be called. But they "exist" at compile-time and therefor will be optimized, right?

Comment: @exocortex It is like you wrote them by hand, just that the compiler is doing that for you.

Comment: I realized that this would be dynamic at runtime, right?

Comment: @exocortex Yes, of course.